# reference on Object which was transfered as parameter

Tags: java, object, reference

> 3rd Code Sample contains the error - how to solve?

In the following code I have generated a method called "generator".
This method receives a JTextField and a JLabel as parameter.

It generates individual JPanels and adds them onto another JPanel (the one with the Border "Vermieter").
The result should look like this (marked red):

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/stammdateneraffsenguibe.png/

here I am instantiating the the JTextFields as fields:

```
private JTextField txtplzvermieter;
private JTextField txtemailvermieter;
private JTextField txtgeburtsdatumvermieter;
private JTextField txthandyvermieter;
private JTextField txtidvermieter;
private JTextField txtnamevermieter;
private JTextField txtortvermieter;
private JTextField txtstrassevermieter;
private JTextField txttelefonvermieter;
private JTextField txtvornamevermieter;
```

here I am calling my methode which I described above

```
        public  void vermieterPanel(JPanel verPanel){
         verPanel.add(generator( "ID", txtidvermieter ));
       verPanel.add(generator("Name", txtnamevermieter ));
       verPanel.add(generator( "Vorname", txtvornamevermieter ));
       verPanel.add(generator( "Straße", txtstrassevermieter ));
       verPanel.add(generator("PLZ", txtplzvermieter ));
       verPanel.add(generator( "Ort", txtortvermieter ));
       verPanel.add(generator( "Geburtsdatum", txtgeburtsdatumvermieter ));
       verPanel.add(generator( "Telefon", txttelefonvermieter ));
       verPanel.add(generator("Handy", txthandyvermieter ));
       verPanel.add(generator( "E-Mail", txtemailvermieter ));
```

and here is the methode generator which contains the error:

```
      public JPanel generator(String lableText, JTextField s){   // generiert ein Panel mit einer Zeile aus lable + TextFeld

     JPanel gens = new JPanel();
     JLabel lable = new JLabel(lableText);
     lable.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,25));

     s = new JTextField();
     s.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));


    gens.add(lable);
    gens.add(s);
    return gens;
  }
```

later I can't get a reference on my TeftFields with `.getText();` because I have created a reference onto a new JTextField-Object here `s = new JTextField();`

If I remove the line in order to access my Objects I get a Null-Pointer exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you will get an exception, because you are passing the JTextield before you initialize it!!
you are just declaring it,
initialize it with the new keyword before passing it as parameter.

Comment: Whops. Forget to mention that call a methode initComponents which references the JTextFields.

Even if I declare the JTextFields like this:

 private JTextField txtplzvermieter = new JTextField();
    private JTextField txtemailvermieter= new JTextField();
    private JTextField txtgeburtsdatumvermieter= new JTextField();
    private JTextField txthandyvermieter= new JTextField();
    private JTextField txtidvermieter = new JTextField();

I still get the same NullPointer

Comment: Debug the code and moniter your field at the point of the entrance of generator and see whats happening

Comment: THX! When I debuged I saw that the generator()-methode was just fine!

The error was here:

mieterPanel(mietPanel);
mieterPanel(mietObjektPanel);

The second line caused the error because "mietObjektPanel" contained just some random stuff (causing the null pointer I think) AND added it to mieterPanel instead a new Panel... when I created a new panel and built the mietObjektPanel with the generator()-methode It worked like a charm. Never used the debugger before so I learnd a new skill - thx

Answer (score 0):

The original values are never being made. You need to do this

```
private JTextField txtplzvermieter = new JTextField();
```

for each of them. But it has to be outside the method, not inside.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I already tried that.

If I remove the line then I get a nullPointerException:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at database.Gui.generator(Gui.java:192)
 at database.Gui.mieterPanel(Gui.java:173)
 at database.Gui.stammdatenErfassen(Gui.java:139)
 at database.Gui.actionPerformed(Gui.java:241)

Answer (score 0):

In *java* you can't pass an object as reference, it never happens
this was the purpose of creating *java* language, minimal memory management
If you pass an object as a parameter, the copy of the reference of the object will be passed
so every change on the objects' `field`s will be reflected except when assigning it with a new object with the `new` keyword, here you will loose the grab of your object
try making your *JField* s as global `class` `field`s and don't pass them to a method through paramters' section.

Comment: thx - this was very useful!

My JFields are already global class fiels!

If I can t pass the reference on the object how can I write the methode "generator" universal so that it generates the JPanel (with JLabel and JTextfield) for every of these TextFields?